# Slidesow from pdf

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf-to-html

if someone know that html5slides by google or [hakim framework](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/5)  also works with multi pages pdf? I'd like run slideshow but based on many pdf files. Sometimes 1 page, other many pages. Each page should be 1 slide in slideshow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you can just embed a pdf page in a slide. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291813/774086)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What do you think many better is use some console software to convert pdf2html5 and next use normal slideshow library.

Because every pdf I will upload earlier and can prepare in php or unix console software.

Comment: I never tried pdf2html5, but I have a feeling they are like saving a .docx to html. What you get might not be what you expect.